# Error al leer Api de Google hojas de calculo con Retrofit2

Tags: java, android-studio, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-api, retrofit

estoy tratando de leer los datos de una hoja de  google con retrofit2, pero al acceder me esta arrojando este error:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: baseUrl must end in /: https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/12f8EEM27sdx_-nqmyUbciSQpdfoVqgrgSrsCkeXT7S8/values/BASE!A1:D?key=AIzaSyAJz5cv2JOo6GjJAxhvy_B5H2t472UTQw4
```

Según he leído es por un "/" al final de la URL, pero si agrego me da el mismo error.

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
.baseUrl("https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/12f8EEM27sdx_-nqmyUbciSQpdfoVqgrgSrsCkeXT7S8/values/BASE!A1:D?key=AIzaSyAJz5cv2JOo6GjJAxhvy_B5H2t472UTQw4")
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
.build();
```

Esta es mi interfaz

```
import com.example.formsaide.Entidades.Codigos;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.POST;
import retrofit2.http.Path;

public interface JsonPlaceHolderApi {


   @GET("posts") //indica el metodo de acceso ala URL
   Call<List<Codigos>> getCodigos();  
}
```

alguien me podría indicar que puedo hacer, gracias.

Comment: Agrégale el / al final de la URL  y quitas esta línea .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
Si no vas a usar Gson para convertir en json el resultado.

Comment: @Omar, gracias, sin embargo este no es el error ya lo he intentado, pero no funciona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El mensaje de error indica el problema:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: baseUrl must end in /:

al definir la url base de la API debes usar una url que debe terminar con el caracter "/", en cambio estas definiendo una url base que no tiene este valor, debería ser:

```
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/
```

de acuerdo a la documentación la url base debería ser:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
.baseUrl("https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/")
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
.build();
```

y en la interface que defines como data source es donde se define el recurso, es un ejemplo:

```
public interface JsonPlaceHolderApi {
    @GET("12f8EEM27sdx_-nqmyUbciSQpdfoVqgrgSrsCkeXT7S8/values/BASE!A1:D?key=AIzaSyAJz5cv2JOo6GjJAxhvy_B5H2t472UTQw4")
    public  Call<List<Codigos>> getCodigos();  
}
```

Te sugiero revises tu implementación, este es un ejemplo de una petición de API usando Retrofit:

[GOOGLE SPREADSHEETS COMO FUENTE DE DATOS PARA UNA APLICACIÓN DE ANDROID QUE UTILIZA RETROFIT](http://equinox.one/blog/2015/10/01/Use-Google-Spreadsheets-as-data-for-an-Android-app/)

Comment: Jorge muchas gracias por tu ayuda, ya tengo que revisar la URL , ya que al correrlo me da "unable to resolve host sheets google com no adress associated with hostname, android studio", imagino que es de GoogleApi